# Assembly: Traversing a binary search tree

Tags: assembly, recursion, x86

I am trying to traverse a binary search tree in-order, and place the data (sorted) in an array. 
for some reason, the pointer to the current position in the array is not moving right.

This is the decleration of the DS:

```
TreeRoot    DWORD              Null (left child)
            DWORD   Null (right child)
            SDWORD   6 (numeric value)
```

and this is the function I'm trying to write:

```
TreeToArray PROC
    rootPtr=8;
    ArrayPtr=rootPtr+4;

    ;Saving the Registers 
    push ebp;
    mov ebp,esp;
    push esi;
    push edx;
    push ebx;
    push edi;
    push ecx;

Check:
    mov esi,rootPtr[ebp]; esi holds the current root
    mov edi, ArrayPtr[ebp] ;edi holds the pointer to the array
    cmp esi,Null ;if root=null
    je Done2;

LeftSubTree:
    push edi
    push BinTreeLeft[esi]
    call TreeToArray; recursive call for left sub tree

Visit:
    mov ebx,BinTreeValue[esi] ;getting the value of the node
    mov [edi],ebx
    add edi,4

RightSubTree:
    push edi
    push BinTreeRight[esi]
    call TreeToArray; recursive call for right sub tree

Done2:
    pop ecx;
    pop edi;
    pop ebx
    pop edx
    pop esi
    pop ebp
    ret 8;

TreeToArray ENDP
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code right now looks like this (if spelled in C):

```
typedef struct tNode
{
  struct tNode* pLeftChild;
  struct tNode* pRightChild;
  int Value;
} tNode;

void TreeToArray(tNode* pNode, int* pArrayElement)
{
  if (pNode == NULL) return;

  TreeToArray(pNode->pLeftChild, pArrayElement);

  *pArrayElement = pNode->Value;
  pArrayElement++;

  TreeToArray(pNode->pRightChild, pArrayElement);
}
```

You are "moving" the pointer only when going to the right child node and forgetting to advance the pointer when going back to the parent node.

What you want to do instead is:

```
int* TreeToArray(tNode* pNode, int* pArrayElement)
{
  if (pNode == NULL) return pArrayElement;

  pArrayElement = TreeToArray(pNode->pLeftChild, pArrayElement);

  *pArrayElement = pNode->Value;
  pArrayElement++;

  pArrayElement = TreeToArray(pNode->pRightChild, pArrayElement);

  return pArrayElement;
}
```